# Python importing submodules from submodule

Tags: python, import

I have got a problem when using python imports. I wrote a finished module, that itself uses several submodules (those are imported).

e.g.

```
module:
   main_class.py
   submodule1.py
   ....
```

Now I want to use this finished module by another supermodule, so the folder structure would change like this

```
supermodule:
    main_class_super.py     -- this class imports module.main_class
    module:
       main_class.py
       submodule1.py
       ....
```

However now all imports that are used in the code of `main_class.py` inside the module fail (I guess because the import now works in the namespace of `main_class_super.py`)

Any idea how to solve this problem without restructuring the entire sources?

---

The concrete error:

In my `main_class.py` I use the line:

```
import submodule1
```

In my `supermodule.py` I use the line:

```
import module.main_class
```

When executing the superclass that imports `module.main_class` of course the `import submodule1` line is executed as well, but fails as it can not find the module in the namespace of `supermodule.py`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on python 2 you should add `from __future__ import absolute_import`  to your files (not needed on 3) so you can do the imports like [Guido states in PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)

According to this you should

- Make sure all your package folders have a `__init__.py` in it to mark them as importable
- In main_class.py: replace `import submodule1` or `import module.submodule1` with `from . import submodule1`
- In main_class_super.py: replace `import module.main_class` with `from .module import main_class`

This way you don't have to care about any outer package structure.

The option to use absolute and explicit relative imports [was added](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports) in Python 2.5.

Comment: Er, i think i do not quite get how this can help me. Given my folder structure, how would i do the import of the submodule1.py inside the supermodule.py?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, by i encountered another problem. Inside those submodules several modules import the same other modules (e.g. submodule1 imports submodule2 and 3 and submodule2 also imports submodule3. Then this import inside submodule2 wont work. (even though i changed it to from . import submodule3). All other imports just work fine

Comment: Sorry, without directory layout (what files are in what folders?)  i cannot help on that

Comment: Structure is the same, only that there is not only submodule1.py on the lowest level but also submodule2.py and submodule3.py.